# Accept donations to a nonprofit

Tags: paypal

I work for a registered nonprofit that runs two music camps and would like to accept charitable donations via their Wordpress website.

Using their existing tools -- NinjaForms and PayPal -- I made a form to collect donor information: name, mailing address, and email. When they submit the form they are taken to the PayPal page. There, if they choose to pay by credit or debit card, they must enter basically the same information a second time: name, billing address, etc., plus their card info. This is a bad user experience.

What plugins/tools/methods can I use so that the donor only has to enter each thing once, yet would still capture the non-PayPal-related donor information into the Wordpress database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different forms of PayPal. It sounds like you are using PayPal Standard, which always takes the visitor to PayPal's website to process the payment.

There are a couple of different PayPal Pro type accounts where you can have the visitor fill out a single form, including their payment information *if* they are using a credit or debit card, and the form will both save to the WP database and process the payment with PayPal as the gateway. However, these accounts also require that you allow PayPal *account* checkout as a second option, in which case the visitor fills out the form on your website but when they submit the form they are taken to PayPal's site to log in and complete the purchase. Since they are using a PayPal account, they just enter their email and password and don't have to re-type their address or other details. These Pro accounts do come at a monthly fee - you might want to call PayPal to discuss your options. Being a nonprofit, they will give you a discount on the fees they charge to process payments.

I am not familiar enough with NinjaForms to know whether it integrates with these types of PayPal accounts. You might need to move to a different form system. Gravity Forms is one I know supports this type of payment, and I use it in the way described to receive donations and also capture the donors' contact information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look at flipping your work flow (right term?) so that they go to PayPal first, then after the donation has been made, go back to your website and verify their account details. We don't collect donations but we do use PayPal standard buttons for people to register on our website for online training.

Our process is 1) make payment on PayPal (credit card or PayPal), then PayPal is able to send us back all the information that they already have collected (email and street address - most of the time) through their IPN relay process. We collect this in our database (albeit, it's a pretty customzied hack).

It keeps visitors from having to enter data twice.

Comment: This is a great solution if all your payments send IPN notifications. Some transactions do not (like credit/debit card subscriptions, if you process them through Payflow) so just be aware you need to double-check that you can receive notifications for each type if you want to capture everyone's info.